# multiprocessing slows down when using torch

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, scipy, multiprocessing

I am using `differential_evolution` from `scipy` with `workers` to parallel the calculations. And I switch to `pytorch` from `numpy` to speed up the code.

```
from torch.multiprocessing import set_start_method,Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #device = get_device()
    device = torch.device('cpu') # testing with cpu
    num_workers=int(sys.argv[1])
    set_start_method("spawn",force=True)
    pool=Pool(num_workers)
    results = differential_evolution(likelihood, seed=np.random.seed(0),workers=pool.map,
                                             callback=print_de, bounds=bounds, maxiter=1500,
                                             disp=True,recombination=0.1,mutation=(0.9,1),
                                             constraints=NonlinearConstraint(positive_definite, lb=0, ub=np.inf),
                                             popsize=25,
                                             polish=False
                                             )
```

In my own laptop (m1 macbook) this works fine either using `torch.multiprocessing` or `multiprocessing` (simply set `workers=int(sys.argv[1])`).

When I test this in HPC with 256 cores in 1 node, it slows down a lot. Using `torch.multiprocessing` is faster than `multiprocessing`, but still one iteration is much slower than when I don't do parallel.

When I use `top`, I can see the correct number of `python` instances are running, but the cpu usage is more than 100%, some even with 1000% per `python`, can this be the problem? When I use `numpy` the cpu usage is almost 100%.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is the reasoning for using torch to speed up code? I would bet that numpy will outperform torch in majority of tasks.

Comment: Furthermore, please try to make code samples runnable as is. At least in cases where problem can be reduced to reasonable size.

Comment: Now I figured that the speedup by pytorch is due to multithreading, and there is a lot of overhead when using multiprocessing such that using numpy is a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, in 99% of cases setting `workers=-1` is going to be superior.

Comment: How long is `likelihood` taking to run? If it's very short the run time may be dominated by spawning a new process, loading libraries, etc.

Comment: it takes about 2 minutes using numpy, and takes 45s using pytorch. I have some big matrix operations such as multiplications, so I guess `pytorch` is faster when `workers=1` but not so when using multiprocess due to multithreading?

Comment: @jasmine To clarify, is that 2 minutes per function invocation, or 2 minutes overall?

Comment: 2 mins per function iteration

Answer (score 0):

Each situation is unique. But here are some pointers:

1. You only want to use enough parallelism that there is no oversubscription.
2. Parallelism involves overhead from thread creation, sending jobs to different workers, etc. If the overhead is too much then it may be better to do serial calculation
3. Vectorization often furnishes benefits. This is where your objective function gets sent a lot of parameter vectors at once. If you can efficiently deal with this (including implementing your own parallisation), then this may be better than differential_evolution doing the parallel computation.
4. Sometimes it's better to parallelise within your own objective function than to parallelise the solver.
5. If bottle neck is computation think of implementing your objective function in Cython/C. However, for matrix multiplication of large matrices you need to be using BLAS.